# I made a Nuget Package that I use in other projects. Do I have to wait everytime I update it?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I'm building an Azure Function that depends on another project I'm building that's on Nuget. Everytime I update the nuget project, I publish the updates to https://nuget.org. Then I wait for the validation. Then I update my other project to pull the latest version. It's really annoying waiting for the validation... sometimes a couple times per day.

Is there a way I can use my nuget package without waiting for validation to complete? Keep in mind I'm developing both packages side-by-side on the same laptop.

Comment: use a project reference instead of a package reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three levels to doing this efficiently:

1. Whenever possible, do local development within the same solution using project references instead of package references. As zivkan said in the comments, this "inner loop" is fastest. Do this until you need to test the package itself (e.g., making sure it installs correctly).
2. Use a [local NuGet feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds) if you are able to test the package without hosting it on a cloud repository. (`nuget add my-package.1.0.0.nupkg -source C:\somedirectory\localnuget`) Visual Studio and the `nuget` CLI can both be configured to look in a local directory, which makes the testing loop much quicker.
3. If your Azure functions must get the package from a real hosted repository, use [MyGet](https://myget.org) (or if you want to DIY it, [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/open-source/)) to host your own NuGet feed. Publishing your packages to that feed and consuming them from your function should be faster than waiting for official verification on nuget.org.

Comment: This is not a great way to develop packages, because after you run that command, the package will be in your global packages folder (GPF) and if you find a bug in the package, you'll need to increment the version or manually delete the package from the GPF. It's so much easier to develop packages using a project reference and then pack and publish only when complete.

Comment: @zivkan I agree that a project reference is the right way to go if everything is in the same solution. From the way AskYous worded the question, it did not seem like that was the case - it seems like they need to depend on an installed package.

Comment: "Keep in mind I'm developing both packages side-by-side on the same laptop." I'd temporarily change the package reference to a project reference, finish development, then change it back to a package before commit to source control.

Comment: @zivkan The problem is that then you are not testing the package, you are testing a referenced project. So if something goes south during the pack step, you will not know, and end up pushing a broken package. And honestly, how much work is it to run `rmdir C:\somedirectory\localnuget\my-package` before you do `nuget add`? You're already in the command shell anyway...

Comment: @IanKemp Exactly - if the need is to test the _package_ (including whether it installs correctly), a project reference won't work. Otherwise, project references > package references.

Comment: test the package after getting the c# code working. Optimise for the inner loop when you're working in it, then do the other "engineering" stuff when it's appropriate. I've seen too many people trying to add features in their package and complain about the slow cycle between change a line of code in the package project and being able to test their consuming project.

Comment: I agree that an in-solution loop is fastest. Updated my answer to reflect that there is a spectrum of ways to do this, from "very fast" to "slightly faster than waiting for official NuGet verification".

Comment: Hello everyone. So I did option 1 and it worked. But I then pushed my changes to GitHub and Azure picked up the changes (using continuous delivery) and it tried to update the Azure Function. But it erred saying it that the other project doesn't exist. You can see the .sol and .csproj [here](https://github.com/islaam-database). I can post this as another SO post if necessary. Is the solution to do option 3 instead?

Comment: @AskYous I think option 3 is your best bet, yes.